# Django admin: Integrity error caused by signal

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-admin

I have a standard `UserProfile` model which has a `OneToOneField` field to `auth.User` model.

Every `User` has to have one and only one `UserProfile` so I need `UserProfile` object to be created allways when `User` is created.

The obvious solution is to create a `post_save` singal:

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

**PROBLEM:**

This approach works when `user` registered themselves or when `user` was created programatically (eg. via shell).

The problem is when `user` is being created through `django-admin`. It raises:

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "main_userprofile_user_id_key" DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(30) already
>   exists.

I've added a `UserProfile` inline into the `User` admin page which means that there are two forms - for `User` creation and for `UserProfile` creation.

```
admin.site.unregister(User)


class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        # (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    #
    ordering = ('username',)
    inlines = [UserProfileInline]
    list_display = ['id', 'username', 'userprofile__display_name','last_login']
```

Now, when admin is creating a new `user` via `django-admin` and fills at least one `UserProfile` form field, django tries to create a `UserProfile` for the `user` two times which returns error. Once it is created because of `signal` and the second time because there was at least one form field of `UserProfile` form filled.

Do you know how to make it work?

**EDIT**

I would add a condition into the `signal`:

```
if not getattr(instance,'userprofile'):
    # create userprofile
```

but the signal is being called before `UserProfile` modelform from admin is saved so it won't help.

Comment: By the way, you can also create a `UserProfile` without using signals - you can override model's `save()` method and create it there before `User` is saved.

Comment: If you implemented inlines, have you tried overriding `save_related` instead ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to implement @Chiefir's advice as an User proxy model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProxy(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self):
        UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=self)
        super(UserProxy, self).save()
```

and commented out the signals line:

```
# signals.post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

See also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#proxy-models .